# Unable to insert data into mysql database using php form

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to learn some PHP using the book titled *PHP for Absolute Beginners*. I am trying to implement some blog design code given in the book using WAMP and editplus. When I try to insert the data using PHP form, all I get is NULL values in the database table. Here is a piece of code for inserting values into the DB.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'
&& $_POST['submit']=='Save Entry'
&& !empty($_POST['title'])
&& !empty($_POST['entry']))
{
// Include database credentials and connect to the database
include_once 'db.inc.php';
$db = new PDO(DB_INFO, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

// Save the entry into the database
$sql = "INSERT INTO entries (title, entry) VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($title, $entry));
$stmt->closeCursor();

// Get the ID of the entry we just saved
$id_obj = $db->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$id = $id_obj->fetch();
$id_obj->closeCursor();

// Send the user to the new entry
header('Location: ../admin.php?id='.$id[0]);
exit;
}
// If both conditions aren't met, sends the user back to the main page
else
{
header('Location: ../admin.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

When I check the apache error log I see this:

```
[Sun May 27 19:21:24 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined 
variable: title in C:\\wamp\\www\\examples\\simple_blog\\inc\\update.inc.php
on line 14, referer: http://localhost/examples/simple_blog/admin.php?id=8
[Sun May 27 19:21:24 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: 
http://localhost/examples/simple_blog/admin.php?id=8
[Sun May 27 19:21:24 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() 
C:\\wamp\\www\\examples\\simple_blog\\inc\\update.inc.php:0, referer:    
http://localhost/examples/simple_blog/admin.php?id=8
[Sun May 27 19:21:24 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined 
variable: entry in C:\\wamp\\www\\examples\\simple_blog\\inc\\update.inc.php 
on line 14, referer: http://localhost/examples/simple_blog/admin.php?id=8
[Sun May 27 19:21:24 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: 
http://localhost/examples/simple_blog/admin.php?id=8
[Sun May 27 19:21:24 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() 
C:\\wamp\\www\\examples\\simple_blog\\inc\\update.inc.php:0, referer: 
http://localhost/examples/simple_blog/admin.php?id=8
```

I don't know what these errors are. Please help me.

Comment: You are using variables that you have not defined. `$title` does not exist, but `$_POST['title']` does. You are already using the correct variables in your if conditional, so why not when executing the query?

Comment: You haven't defined `$entry`. I hope this book wasn't written with `register_globals` turned on. If it's that old, you should probably get a new book.

Comment: @minitech they do mention `PDO` at least :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly your server is configured so that `$_POST['title']` is not automatically aliased as `$title`. Initialize `$title = $_POST['title']` and same for other used `$_POST` items manually.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'
&& $_POST['submit']=='Save Entry'
&& !empty($_POST['title'])
&& !empty($_POST['entry']))
{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $entry = $_POST['entry'];

...
}
```

Comment: Why would $_POST['title'] ever be aliased as $title automatically?

Comment: @Flukey: PHP has (had?) an option `register_globals`, which made all variables from POST, GET and COOKIE available as global variables.

Comment: It it not enabled by default and with good reason. `This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.`

Comment: Yes, but it seems, that code provided in question assumes that register_globals is on.

Comment: I think this book is a bit old so it might have been configured as register_globals as ON, so there was no need to declare the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The errors/warnings are pretty self explanatory; you must define variables before you can use them (most of the times):

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$entry = $_POST['entry'];
```

Anywhere above line 14 will do.

PHP has a `register_globals` setting that would do this automatically for you, but because it's a configurations setting, you can't reliably use it. I believe that in the latest version of PHP it's no longer available.

Comment: I thought $_POST['title']; will automatically get defined as $title so I never explicitly defined it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @omsai some php configurations allow for this, but it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: title` means that there isn't a variable called title. And looking at your code, you're almost there, but have just missed out two lines.
YOu need to assign your `$_POST` data the variable. Add the follow lines just inside the if statement and you should be ok

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
$entry=$_POST['entry'];
```